# How do I get an iframe to print out properly with rmd markdown using R?

Tags: r, iframe, r-markdown, pandoc

I am trying to get this R markdown document with embedded code that directly produces HTML/iframe, but haven't been able to do so.

Here is the markdown:

`{r results='asis', warning=FALSE,eval=TRUE, echo=FALSE, comment=''}
print("<iframe width=\"560\" height=\"315\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/9bZkp7q19f0?rel=0\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>")`

Instead of having an iframe in the generated HTML, I get this:

```
<p>[1] “&lt;iframe width=&quot;560&quot; height=&quot;315&quot; src=&quot;<a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/9bZkp7q19f0?rel=0\" class="uri">http://www.youtube.com/embed/9bZkp7q19f0?rel=0\</a>” frameborder=&quot;0&quot; allowfullscreen&gt;</iframe>&quot;</p>
```

I also tried with the pandoc option:

```
html_document:
    md_extensions: -autolink_bare_uris
```

still does not give me the desired result

```
<p>[1] “&lt;iframe width=&quot;560&quot; height=&quot;315&quot; src=&quot;http://www.youtube.com/embed/9bZkp7q19f0?rel=0&quot; frameborder=&quot;0&quot; allowfullscreen&gt;</iframe>”</p>
```